# How I Populate a list<> in two different Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Based on the answers and comments that I have been provide, I made the following modifications. Since I have other things than the two Gridviews I am not making any modifications to the load method. I am trying to split the collection when I bind it.

The Gridviews are:

```
<asp:GridView id ="gvClosed" runat = "server"/>
<asp:GridView id ="gvDraft" runat = "server"/>
```

The Bind:It does bind but the same data in both GV's

```
private void bindFiles(bool reload)
        {
            int size = 10;

            List<File> closedFiles = new List<File>();
            List<File> draftFiles = new List<File>();
            if (ViewState["Files"] != null)
                closedFiles = (List<File>)ViewState["Files"];
                //draftFiles= (List<File>)ViewState["Drafts"];
            else
                closedFiles = loadFiles(((User)Session["currentUser"]).ID);


            draftFiles = loadFiles(((User)Session["currentUser"]).ID);
            List<File> listFiles = new List<File>();
            foreach (File f in closedFiles)
                listFiles.Add(f);

            bool loadPrimary = Session["filterPrimary"] != null ? Convert.ToBoolean : false;
            bool loadAll = Session["ViewAllUserFiles"] != null ? Convert.ToBoolean : false;


            foreach (File d in draftFiles)
                listFiles.Add(d);

            if (loadPrimary)
                listFiles = listFiles.FindAll(delegate(File f) 
                { 
                return f.Modified == true; 
                });

            //Binding to the database

            gvFiles.DataSource = listFiles;
            gvFiles.DataBind();

            gvDraftFiles.DataSource = listFiles;
            gvDraftFiles.DataBind();

            showHideSortArrows(gvFiles, GridViewType.File);
            //showHideSortArrows(gvDraftFiles, GridViewType.Drafts);
```

Comment: So, what have you tried so far, and how is it not doing what you want it to?

Comment: @mason, the above code is what I tried. The List<T> Closed will return everything from the database. The part I need help is implementing List<T>drafts. As you can see, since I couldn't be able to figure that out the code is commented out

Comment: You have not shown any code that loads data from a database. That's probably an important thing to do.

Comment: @mason, okay, this the part that loads

Comment: @mason I have updated my original post to show the load method

Comment: What is the property on your object that indicates draft status and closed status? And can you indicate how you set it.

Answer (score 0):

Split your collection into two collections and then bind them separately individually to their appropriate GridViews.  Better yet, pass a parameter to your loading method that you can use for your query to specify what sort of list you're trying to load.  That way you can just load your lists using one method and not have to split anything.

Comment: @B.K.okay, here is the part that I want to split into two and bind it to differnt gv. The load method is the same for the page. I want to change this templist is the list that I would like to split into two. private void bindLists(bool reload)
        {
            int size = 20;

            List<AllLists> tempLists = new List<AllLists>();

Comment: @user3495554 What's `AllLists`?

Comment: it's all the lists that I have in the table.I have edited my original post. I tried to split it's binding the same data on both grid-views.

Answer (score 0):

If both lists contain the same data and you want to bind the same data to two or more controls, you can do that. you don't need to split it into different lists.

Even if you wish to bind only a subset of data to different controls, you can achieve that using Linq, since Linq resultsets are always IEnumerable of T.

For instance:

```
    List<string> someList = GetStuffFromDatabase();

    // binding to first control, all data
    datagridControl1.DataSource = someList;  

    // binding to second control with subset of data
    dropdownListControl1.DataSource = someList.AsEnumerable().Where( t => t.StartsWith("US-") );
```

and so on... The same applies to all kinds of collections... Dictionaries, et al.

Comment: Well, the idea is that you can bing N number of times to the same structure. You can do the same from Markup as well, with appropriate modifications.

Comment: The only problem I see with that binding is that it has to run that query expression every time the collection is updated or control is loaded.  It's not noticeable on a small collection, but would be annoying on a larger one.

Comment: @B.K., I have edited my previous code the current one does bind but it's binding the same data in both grid-views. I know my split is not functioning as it suppose to. Would you help me on that please, thanks?

Answer (score 0):

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView id="gvDraft" runat="server" />
<asp:GridView id="gvClosed" runat="server" />
```

**C#:**

```
closedList = new List<list>();
draftList = new List<list>();

if (ds.Tables.Count != 0)
{
   foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
   {
       List ls = new List();
       if (dr["list_id"] != DBNull.Value)
       {
            ls.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["list_id"]);
            //I have more this is just for example

            if(dr["WhateverIndicatesClosed"] == true)
            {
               closedList.Add(ls);
            }else{
               draftList.Add(ls);
            }
       }
   }
}

gvDraft.DataSource = draftList;
gvDraft.DataBind();

gvClosed.DataSource = closedList;
gvClosed.DataBind();
```

You could also use linq to separate the lists, but as you are iterating through the dataset anyway, you may as well split the lists there.

Comment: I have tried your method. The problem I am having I can't make a lot of modification on the load method since that is the home page and has a lot of info other than the two gridviews. My goal is to use the one List<string>ListsFromDB = new List<list>();a generic one and split that into two not in my load method but on this method            private void bindLists(bool reload)
List<T> closed = new List<T>();
 //List<T> drafts = new List<T>();